# Phonegap system notification plugin

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to get this plugin to work but it wont work for me.

https://github.com/saileshmittal/phonegap-system-notification-plugin

I think im doing something wrong with calling the plugin in the Javascript file. This is what i have so far;

```
        var not_title   = 'MELVIN';
    var not_text    = 'Zou dit werken?';
    var not_tText   = 'of toch niet?';

    navigator.systemNotification.onBackground();
    //navigator.systemNotification.onForeground();
    navigator.systemNotification.createStatusBarNotification(not_title, not_text, not_tText);
    //navigator.systemNotification.updateNotification(not_title, not_text, 1);
```

this is what is have in SystemNotification.js in the bottom of it;

```
PhoneGap.addConstructor(function () {

if (typeof(navigator.systemNotification) == "undefined") {
    navigator.systemNotification = new SystemNotification();
    navigator.systemNotification.touch();  //this ensures that the plugin is added when phonegap kicks off
}
//PhoneGap.addPlugin("systemNotification", new systemNotification());
PluginManager.addService("systemNotification", "com.SystemNotification.SystemNotification");

});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since you are explicitly calling "onBackground" I am assuming you want to get system-notifications when app is in foreground too. Can you please put console logs in create...Notification method and see if its getting called? Also make sure that you are doing everything the README says.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working now after some adjustments;

```
PhoneGap.addConstructor(function () {

PhoneGap.addPlugin("SystemNotification", new SystemNotification());
PluginManager.addService("SystemNotification", "com.phonegap.plugins.SystemNotification.SystemNotification");

window.plugins.SystemNotification.touch();
});

            window.plugins.SystemNotification.onBackground();
        window.plugins.SystemNotification.createStatusBarNotification('', '', '');
```